# Grouping whole website together and centering it

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how i can take my whole website group it together as a whole and center it within my page. As of right now my webpage is slightly centered to the right. I have tried multiple tutorials but they are mainly geared towards sites that have just been created. When i do what they say to my site everything just goes out of place. So basically how do i take my whole website group it all and stick it in the middle.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls2xknqa/

Code:

```
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 <img src="/Users/alexparsons/Desktop/AvoArt/img/logo2.jpg" style="position: inherit;     left: 10px; margin: 0 auto; ">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">About Me</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Request Order</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    <img src="/Users/alexparsons/Desktop/AvoArt/img/art1.jpg" style=" position: inherit;        left: 40px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 40px;">
<p style="font-family: Abel, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 500px; margin-       top: -250px;"> This is some random text. This random text will be filled later with other     text that has to do with the picture to the right. The picture to the right has a lot to     with some other stuff that is problebly very important. This is random text. This is random   text. This is random text. This is random text. This is random text. This is random text.       This is random text. </p>

<div class="line" style="background-color: #000; width: 1015px; height: 1px; margin-top:    -200px;">
<div class="line" style="margin-left: 82px; background-color: #000; width: 100px; height:    4px; margin-top: -200px;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `<body>` tag insert `<div id='container'>` and just before your `</body>` tag insert `</div>`.

Then in your CSS, add the following rule;

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Obviously you can set the width as you see fit.

When specifying two arguments for your margin, the first is the top and bottom margin and the second is left and right. Setting left and right to `auto` means the margin will "fill" the remaining space in the parent element (in this case `<body>`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely worked for everything but my navbar. I think the css  that i put on jsfiddle overrides this for some reason. But this was very close.

Comment: Specify an absolute width for the nav (less than the width of the container) and you should be fine. You can centre that in the container with the same margin code too.